# Generate equal size batches from N numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have N NumPy arrays of shape `data[n,m,3]`. I want to fit/squeeze/split/slice/reshape them into N' arrays of shape `new_data_#[1000,m,3]` where # is the indexing of new arrays. The problem is that n can be smaller, or bigger than 1000. When it is smaller somehow I should fill the rest of 1000 capacity of new_array with the next array, and when it is bigger than 1000 I should make a new_data_# and add the rest to that one. I don't know how to manage this. Here is a pseudo-code but it can't be done this way, for example, the while maybe is not necessary. The output can be written to the disk or returned in a new data format.

```
def array2blocks(array_files)
 for each N in array_files:
    N = data = np.random.rand(n, m, 3)
    new_data = np.zeros((1000, m, 3), dtype=np.float32)
    j=0
    index = 0
    while j <= new_data.shape[0]:
        for i in range(data.shape[0]):
            print("--->", data[i,:,:])
            print (i)
            if i <= new_data.shape[0]:
                # here first we should check the left capacity of new_data and then insert data into it
                # new_data[i, :, :] = data[i, :, :] #this overrides previous items so not correct
                print(new_data)
            else:
                print('n>1000')
                new_data_name = 'new_data' + '_' + str(index)
                # here fill rest of the data in the new_data
                ...
                index += 1
            #when capacity is full write it to the disk
    print(new_data)
```

**UPDATE** with Aaron's old answer:
I replaced 1000 with `batch_size = 5` to make it simple.

```
def numpyarrays2blocks(array_files):
    N1 = np.random.rand(7, 4, 3)
    N2 = np.random.rand(7, 4, 3)
    N3 = np.random.rand(4, 4, 3)
    # array_files = []
    array_files.append(N1)
    array_files.append(N2)
    array_files.append(N3)
    for N in array_files:
        n = N.shape[0]
        m = N.shape[1]
        batch_size = 5
        # N = data = np.random.rand(n, m, 3)
        data = N
        # print(data)
        new_arrays = []
        i = 0  # the current row index to insert
        while i < n:
            new_data = np.zeros((batch_size, m, 3), dtype=np.float32)
            j = min(i + batch_size, n)  # the last row (exclusive) to copy to new_data
            # j - i is the number of rows to copy
            new_data[:j - i, :, :] = data[i:j, :, :]
            print('NEW DATA: ', new_data)
            i = j  # update the index
            new_arrays.append(new_data)
    print(new_arrays)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `data` is used to store the temporary result, and `data_start` is the index to insert rows to `data`.
2. Allocate `data` if it is `None`
3. `yield data` if it is fully filled.

`merge_and_split` is a generator so that the memory demand should be low.

```py
import random
from typing import Iterator

import numpy as np


def merge_and_split(arrays, batch_size) -> Iterator:
    arrays = tuple(arrays)

    dtype = arrays[0].dtype

    data_shape = (batch_size,) + arrays[0].shape[1:]

    assert all(a.shape[1:] == data_shape[1:] for a in arrays), "Shape mismatch"

    data = None
    data_start = 0

    for src in arrays:
        src_index = 0
        src_avail = src.shape[0]

        while src_avail >= 1:
            if data is None:
                # allocate if None
                data = np.zeros(data_shape, dtype=dtype)
                data_start = 0

            num_moved = min(batch_size - data_start, src_avail)
            data[data_start:data_start + num_moved, ...] = src[src_index:src_index + num_moved, ...]

            data_start += num_moved
            src_index += num_moved
            src_avail -= num_moved

            if data_start >= batch_size:
                yield data
                data = None

    if data is not None:
        yield data


def input_arrays():
    number = 10

    r = random.Random(13)

    return [np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(r.randint(1, 5), 4, 3)) for _ in range(number)]


def main():
    # Testing input and output
    arrays = input_arrays()

    # for i, item in enumerate(arrays):
    #     print('input', i, item.shape)
    #     print(item)

    result = list(merge_and_split(arrays, 5))

    # for i, item in enumerate(result):
    #     print('result', i, item.shape)
    #     print(item)

    src_concat = np.vstack(arrays)
    row_number = sum(s.shape[0] for s in arrays)
    print('concatenated', src_concat.shape, row_number)

    out_concat = np.vstack(result)
    print(out_concat.shape)
    print((out_concat[0:row_number, ...] == src_concat).all())  # They are indeed the same


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @Aron thanks and sorry for the late reply. This doesn't do what I expect because it updates the new_data in the while loop every time with zero values: `new_data = np.zeros((1000, m, 3), dtype=np.float32)`. I want new_data in each iteration if has empty capacity then get filled with the rest of the values from the previous file.

Comment: so there are `N * [n,m,3]` data in total. They are concatenated along the first dimension and split into a number of `[batch_size,m,3]` arrays?

Comment: Yes, there are N NumPy arrays. No, they are not concatenated, but if it solves the problem you can concatenate them as long as you return the shape [1000, m, 3]. I think numpy has a limit on the number of dimensions, so if n gets very large, we can't concatenate all of the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) all your original arrays [`split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) them:

```
ars = ... # list of N arrays
ars = np.concatenate(ars, axis=0)
ars = np.split(ars, np.arange(1000, ars.shape[0], 1000))
```

The last line can be written as `ars = np.split(ars, 1000)`, but only if you're sure that the total number of elements is a multiple of 1000, since `np.split` will barf otherwise. Specifying explicit split-points, as with `np.arange`, allows you to have a shorter final segment.

Comment: There isn't any limit on the number or size of arrays that we can concatenate in NumPy?

Comment: Your memory limit, which you likely won't exceed